# Full join - two tables with the same attributes and primary keys but different values. What will be the output when I do a full join?

Tags: sql, triggers

I am writing the trigger function and want to take note of the modification happening on the data. It is for the update, delete and insert. I am trying to use the inserted and deleted tables in the trigger to do a full join on them. But I am not able to figure out if the `result.OrderID` is the primary key.

```
select @orderID = isnull (i.OrderID, d.OrderID)
from inserted i
full join deleted d on i.OrderID = d.OrderID;
```

Comment: Maybe, UNION is better? `select OrderId, 'inserted' FROM inserted UNION select OrderId, 'deleted' FROM deleted`. Why are you trying to assign result of this query into @orderId, what the purpose?

Comment: i am trying to identify the particular row with the primary key orderID which is unique and cannot be changed.i am using it here:                                                                 update SaleOrder
 set LastModified=@Lastmodified
 where OrderID=@orderID

Comment: And what if you deleted several rows, for example? I think you shoul use temp table like `DECLARE @tOrders TABLE (OrderId INT)` (if we are talking about MSSQL)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Triggers are very specific.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correct, then this could be better:

```
UPDATE so
SET LastModified = @LastModified
FROM SaleOrder so
INNER JOIN (SELECT OrderId 
           FROM Inserted 
           UNION
           SELECT OrderId
           FROM Deleted) as t
  ON so.OrderId = t.OrderId
```

Or another way:

```
UPDATE SaleOrder
SET LastModified = @LastModified
WHERE OrderId IN (SELECT OrderId 
                  FROM Inserted 
                  UNION
                  SELECT OrderId
                  FROM Deleted)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use `exists`:

```
update SaleOrder
    set LastModified = @Lastmodified
    where exists (select 1 from inserted i where i.OrderId = SaleOrder.OrderId) or
          exists (select 1 from deleted d where d.OrderId = SaleOrder.OrderId) ;
```